# Print DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE in a file with a bash script

Tags: sql, linux, bash, plsql

I have a pl/SQL query that has a variable .
I want DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to a file used on the machine (linux)
Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some pieces together. Here is my inspiration: [DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE not printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434474/dbms-output-put-line-not-printing)

a) put your plsql in an sql script, e.g. `d.sql` - the key here is ***`set serveroutput`***:

```
set serveroutput on size 30000;
begin
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('my line');
end;
/
exit
```

b) Then write another script - ksh this time - containing:

```
sqlplus /  @d.sql > output.txt
```

If you want to restrain what displays from [sqlplus](/questions/tagged/sqlplus), then read appropriate documentation about [`set` statement](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html)